# CLOSE_WAIT Error when the server process is killed and it respawns immediately

Tags: c++, linux, busybox

I have a process(server) which shall connect to another process(client) on the same machine via sockets(TCP). what is happening is that when the server process is killed using the kill command, it respawns with a new PID and then gives bind error. netstat shows the connection to be in CLOSE_WAIT connection. so the client process shows error operation in progress error:115 and the server gives the bind error: Address in use.

Not sure how I can solve the issue. The programs are in C++ and the sockets are SO_REUSEADDR.

Comment: "I am facing the same issue.". The same as ... ? You seem to refer to another question, but failed to link it. As for the kill command, does your signal handler close the open socket on `SIGTERM`?

Comment: My bad, edited it. Yes I am closing it. But it doesn't seem to work